# Simulation of t copula in Python

Tags: python, t-distribution, copula, inverse-gamma-distribution

I am trying to simulate a t-copula using Python, but my code yields strange results (is not well-behaving):

I followed the approach suggested by [Demarta & McNeil](http://www.ressources-actuarielles.net/EXT/ISFA/1226.nsf/0/303eb11b4d617b79c1257b0800744575/$FILE/t%20copula%20demarta%20mcneil.pdf]) (2004) in "The t Copula and Related Copulas", which states:

[image: t copula simulation]

By intuition, I know that the higher the degrees of freedom parameter, the more the t copula should resemble the Gaussian one (and hence the lower the tail dependency). However, given that I sample from `scipy.stats.invgamma.rvs` or alternatively from `scipy.stats.chi2.rvs`, yields higher values for my parameter `s` the higher my parameter `df`. This does not made any sense, as I found multiple papers stating that for `df`--> `inf`, t-copula --> Gaussian copula.

Here is my code, what am I doing wrong? (I'm a beginner in Python fyi).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import invgamma, chi2, t

#Define number of sampling points
n_samples = 1000
df = 10

calib_correl_matrix = np.array([[1,0.8,],[0.8,1]]) #I just took a bivariate correlation matrix here
mu = np.zeros(len(calib_correl_matrix))
s = chi2.rvs(df)
#s = invgamma.pdf(df/2,df/2) 
Z = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu, calib_correl_matrix,n_samples)
X = np.sqrt(df/s)*Z #chi-square method
#X = np.sqrt(s)*Z #inverse gamma method

U = t.cdf(X,df)
```

My outcomes behave exactly oppisite to what I am (should be) expecting: 
Higher `df` create much higher tail-dependency, here also visually:

```
 U_pd = pd.DataFrame(U)
 fig = plt.gcf()
 fig.set_size_inches(14.5, 10.5)
 pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(U_pd, figsize=(14,10), diagonal = 'kde')
 plt.show()
```

`df=4`:
[image: scatter_plot]

`df=100`:
[image]

It gets especially worse when using the `invgamma.rvs` directly, even though they should yield the same. For dfs>=30 I often receive a ValueError ("ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs")

Thank you very much for your help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As this is a cross-posted question, I am not sure it makes sense to cross-post the corresponding answer as well. I'll just add the link to it on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53491296/318964).